# Remote PowerShell : Error 307

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2

On a Widnows 7 PC, I have an error 307 when I run the `Invoke-Command` or `Enter-PSSession` in PowerShell. I have the two computers in the trusted zone. When I run the same command on a Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2, I don't have the error and the command works perfectly. The target runs Windows Server 2012 R2.

They both run PowerShell v4.0 (for Widnows 7, I upgraded according to MS : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855).

For Windows 7 :

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18444
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2

PS C:\> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 127.0.0.1

[...]HTTP error 307[...]
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 127.0.0.1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (127.0.0.1:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

For Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2 :

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34014
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17400
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2

PS C:\> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 127.0.0.1
[127.0.0.1]: PS C:>
```

Moreover, when I test the connexion with `Test-WSMan`, I get a HTTP error 12152. And the two machines ping the other.

Have you an idea for a possible solution ?

ps : the exact English message when run `Invoke-Command` :

```
[xxxxx] Connecting to remote server srvpwdev01 failed with the following error message : <f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault" Code="2150859023" Machine="xxxxx"><f:Message></f:Message></f:WSManFault> For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (srvpwdev01:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : -2144108273,PSSessionStateBroken
```

I have the number 307 in a French Windows.

Comment: Please show the command that fails and the exact error message.